# PHP STRCHR equivalence to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, strchr

Is there a function in javascript that is equivalent to strchr of php? Please help me. thank you.

Comment: Best reference for JS equivalent functions is http://phpjs.org/

Comment: can it return a value of string?

Answer (score 2):

You should try the [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) method.